# Rails class method scope makes an extra query

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope

I have a relation between two objects. Let's say it like this: Model1 has_many Model2 (That doesn't really matter)

And say, I want to filter-out some of the results:

```
a = Model1.find(123) 
b = a.model2
```

And now, for example, I want to select only EVEN records (by ID)

If I do following: `b.select {|x| x.id % 2 == 0}` then it returns all even records as expected. And NO additional database queries created.

But if I define a class method in the Model2:

```
def self.even_records
   select {|x| x.id % 2 == 0}
end
```

Then, for some magic reason it makes an additional query to database, that looks like it re-instantiated the "b" variable (re-loads the relation):

```
Model2 Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `model2`.* FROM `model2` WHERE `model2`.`model1_id` = 123
```

Why it behaves so ? Is there any way I can fix it ?

P.S I have no fishy callbacks, like `after_find` or whatsoever defined in any of models.

Comment: If you define b = a.model2, can you paste the result of 'b' object.

Comment: What do you want to 'fix'? Do you try this code in console?

Comment: @RailsGuy 1.9.3p448 :186 > b
 => [#<Model2 id: 2, name: "Test", in_use: true>]
b.class => Array

Comment: @MarekLipka Yes, in console. Any issue with console ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Basic difference between these two is that when you call select method on b which is an array, than it calls the enumerable method [select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-select).

```
b.select {|x| x.id % 2 == 0}
```

and when you write in a method, it calls the select method of activerecord query interface.

```
def self.even_records
   select {|x| x.id % 2 == 0}
end
```

BTW Ruby have methods like `even?` and `odd?`, so you can directly call them :

```
even_records = b.select{|x| x.id.even?}
odd_records = b.select{|x| x.id.odd? }
```

**`Edit:`** I found a simple solution for you, you can define a scope in your model `Model2` like below,

```
scope :even_records, -> { where ('id % 2 == 0') }
```

and now if you will call :

```
Model2.even_records
```

you will have your even_records.
Thanks

Comment: Ah. I see. 
But, still, is it possible to use a AR Query Interface, but without any additional queries ?

I know about "even?" and "odd?" methods. But that was just an example
So, the only solution that you think would be just to extend the Array class ?

Answer (score 2):

`ActiveRecord` scopes are evaluated lazily, i.e. scope is evaluated when its result is necessary. When you try this code in console, `inspect` method are called implicitly on every evaluated object, including `ActiveRecord::Relation` instance returned from

```
b = a.model2
```

call. After calling `inspect` on `ActiveRecord::Relation`, scope is evaluated and DB query is created since it's necessary to show `inspect` return value properly.

On the contrary, when you run your code outside rails console,

```
b = a.model2
```

won't produce DB query, thus there will probably be only one database query.